# Using jqTransform on hidden contact form, select box value not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contact-form

Sorry if this is a pain the ass, but I could really use some help here:

http://dev.rjlacount.com/treinaAronson-form/

The contact form can be seen by clicking the "Contact" button on the top left. I'm using the jqTransform jQuery plugin to style it. It's hidden initially with display:none; applied to the div with the ID "panel", and slid in with the following:

```
$("#flip").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#panel").slideToggle("3000");
});
```

With this setup, the contact form isn't displaying the current value of the select box inside its field. If I instead remove the display:none; rule for the panel div from my CSS, and hide the form after the page has loaded with:

```
$("#panel").hide();
```

The form display correctly. Does anybody know how I can make this work and avoid the flash of an open panel I get if I hide it with jQuery after the page loads?

Thanks so much for any advice. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: May I just point out that on that website they spell Treina two different ways?

Comment: @Mahnax That's actually my bad, thanks for pointing it out. It should be spelled Treina; where did you notice a mix-up? (EDIT: If you're talking about the brown area with the social icons, I just noticed that. Fixing now.)

Comment: No problem, it was the brown area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, jqtransform is setting width for a label (currently visible value in a transformed select) to match the width of original select.

If the original select (or its parent) has `display:none` set, and it doesn't have any css width specified, the result of `.width()` on that element is zero.

You can in fact check (using firebug or google chrome dev tools), that it's not that contact form isn't displaying the current value of the select element, but rather displaying it with a width equal to zero.

The easiest solution in your case, is to set (in your css file) fixed width for the selects that are part of a contact form. That way, even though they will be hidden at first, the jqtransform will set correct width for label. For example:

```
/* css declaration */
#change-form select {
    width: 390px;
}
```

*Side note: there are of course other ways to make it work, including tweaking the jqtransform script to fit your specific use case. Part of the script related to setting mentioned width of a label starts on line 289.*

Comment: This did it! Thank you SO much, I was getting really frustrated with it.